# SubMenu Disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, submenu

I have a submenu I am doing with the help of JQuery but when I leave my main LI to go to the SubMenu the sub disappears. From what Ive researched, I see alot of times this is a CSS isue but I cant see anything wrong with my CSS. The only other thing I am wondering is if the HOVER function is not the way to go? Please take a look.

Here is my CSS and JavaScript for the parts in question:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav #about').hover(function (e) {
        $('.nav2').slideDown('normal');
    }, function () {
        $('.nav2').slideUp('normal');
    });
});
</script>


#wrapper
{
margin:9% 10% 1% 10%;
height:40em;
border: solid 3px black;
background-color:#B2B2D9;
overflow:hidden
}           /* Allows inner div to expand to full height of WRAPPER div */



#main
{
height:100%;
background-color:white;
margin-right:2%;
margin-bottom:20%;
margin-left:15%;
padding-top:1em;
padding-left:2em;
}


#col1
{
background-color:#000033;
width:15%;
height:100%;
float:left;
color:#FFF000;
font-family: bold;
font-size: 100%;
padding:0;
}


ul.nav li 
{
position:relative;
width:100%;
}

ul.nav a
{
display: block;
background-color:#B2B2D9;
margin-right:2%;
margin-bottom:1%;
margin-left:1%;
text-decoration:none;
border-top-color:#FFFFFF;
border-right-color:#E6E6E6;
border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF;
border-left-color:#E6E6E6;
border-top-width: 3%;
border-right-width: 3%;
border-bottom-width: 3%;
border-left-width: 3%;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
padding: 2%;
}


ul.nav
{
position:relative;
width:100%;
list-style-type: none;
line-height:1.5em;
padding:0px;
}

ul.nav2 a
{
display: block;
background-color:#000033;
padding:6%; 
margin:0;
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
border-top-color:#FFFFFF;    
border-right-color:#E6E6E6;
border-bottom-color:#FFFFFF;
border-left-color:#E6E6E6;
}


ul.nav2
{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:100%;
display:none;
font-size:100%;
list-style-type: none;
width:7em;
line-height:1.5em;
padding:0px;
}

ul.nav2 li
{ 
line-height:1.3em;
}
```

Here is the part of the page in question:

```
<div id="col1">

<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Home</a></li>
<li><a id="about" href="http://www.alan.com">About</a>

  <ul class="nav2">
  <li><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
  <li><a href="edu.html">Education</a></li>
  </ul>

</li>

<li><a href="http://www.alan.com">New Listings</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Featured Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Town Facts</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.alan.com">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>


</div>


<div id="main">
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
</div>
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle of this?

Comment: You didn't read the manual -> http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Comment: use mouseenter and mouseleave.

Comment: `.slideUp('normal')` ~ What is `'normal'` supposed to be?  It's not anywhere else in your code and it's [not a valid parameter for that method](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).

Comment: normal is a valid parameter..... normal, slow, and fast, all work with slideUp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move your `id="about"` to the `<li>` element it should work more like you would expect (`<li>` is your submenu container, not the `<a>` tag)

```
<li id="about"><a href="http://www.alan.com">About</a>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you BumbleB, and to all who also offered help!